# Sharing Pictures and Text with Facebook SDK 4.2

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent, sdk, publish

I'm trying to share pictures and text with the Facebook SDK 4.2, but when I call the share function (Via SDK or intent) all I get is an Image without text.
Here's the code

```
  Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  shareIntent.setType("image/*");
  shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,   Uri.parse("file://" + mFilepath));
  shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"example");
  shareIntent.setPackage("com.facebook.katana");
  startActivity(shareIntent);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook does not allow pre-filling the messages.
See [this discussion](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/332619626816423) for details.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
// By this method we can post on facebook.
private void publishFeedDialog() {
     Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
     //if(session==null)
     {                      
            // try to restore from cache
            session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(dashBoard);
        }
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "MeetMeUp");
    params.putString("caption", "Discover events nearby, easily create events and invite your friends!");
    params.putString("description", "Finding, creating and sharing activities you’re passionate about are made easy with MeetMeUp. Whether you’re organizing a small gathering with friends, looking for a neighborhood football game or going to a local music concert, MeetMeUp makes it happen. ");
    params.putString("link", "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.meetmeup.activity");
    params.putString("picture", "http://72.167.41.165/meetmeup/webservices/images/aaaaa-05.jpg");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),session, params)).setOnCompleteListener(
            new OnCompleteListener() {

                @Override
                public void onComplete(Bundle values, FacebookException error) {
                    if (error == null) {
                        // When the story is posted, echo the success
                        // and the post Id.
                        final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                        if (postId != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Posted story, id: " + postId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            // User clicked the Cancel button
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                        // User clicked the "x" button
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Publish cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // Generic, ex: network error
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Error posting story", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }

            }).build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

Comment: Shahid, can I know what Package I have to import for session, please? There are 4 different solutions

Comment: for which class?can you please specify?

Comment: private void publishFeedDialog() {
     Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
     //if(session==null)
     {                      
            // try to restore from cache
            session = Session.openActiveSessionFromCache(dashBoard);
        }

I can't find a way to fix session and dashBoard, it says that I have to import them, but by doing this, I get always an error

Comment: please replace dashBoard with your activity

Comment: Did it, but I always get the problem with session. Is it intended as Facebook session?

Comment: import android.service.textservice.SpellCheckerService.Session;
import com.facebook.Session;

Comment: I checked something, your solution is good for an older version of sdk :( 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/android/3.5/class/WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder/

Answer (score 0):

Please check the below code it might help you.

```
Bundle parameters = new Bundle();
parameters.putString("message", category_item_name_desc.getText().toString());
parameters.putString("picture", categoryItemsModel.getImageUrl());
parameters.putString("caption", txtDescription_desc.getText().toString());
facebook.request("/me/feed", parameters, "POST");
```

Comment: it easily posts only the picture